How do I map a data to another Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF)?
I am left with a task to match two arrays(simulated and actual observations) with the help of their cumulative density function (CDF). Accoring to a literature: “At first, CDFs of both actual  and simulated observations are computed. Thereafter, the actual observations have been mapped  according to the simulated CDF to get the corrected observations.”
I started with:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import os
import seaborn as sns

# Function to calculate CDF
def calculate_cdf(data):
    sorted_data = np.sort(data)
    cdf = np.arange(1, len(sorted_data) + 1) / len(sorted_data)
    return sorted_data, cdf

# Function to map observed CDF to simulated CDF
def map_observed_cdf_to_simulated(observed, observed_cdf, simulated_cdf, sorted_simulated):
    return np.interp(observed_cdf, simulated_cdf, sorted_simulated)

# Function to calculate bias, standard deviation, correlation coefficient, and number of points
def calculate_statistics(observed, simulated):
    bias = np.mean(observed - simulated)
    std_dev = np.std(observed - simulated)
    corr_coef = np.corrcoef(observed, simulated)[0, 1]
    num_points = len(observed)
    return bias, std_dev, corr_coef, num_points

# Directory containing data files
data_dir = '/data/swadhin/2022/test/spatial/automated'

# Initialize lists to store all observed and simulated BTs
observed_bt_tir1_all = []
simulated_bt_tir1_all = []
observed_bt_tir2_all = []
simulated_bt_tir2_all = []

# Loop through all files in the directory
for file_name in os.listdir(data_dir):
    if file_name.endswith('.csv'):  # Assuming files are in CSV format
        file_path = os.path.join(data_dir, file_name)
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        
        # Extract TIR1 and TIR2 data
        observed_bt_tir1_all.extend(df['IMG_TIR1'].values)
        simulated_bt_tir1_all.extend(df['sim_bt_tir1'].values)
        observed_bt_tir2_all.extend(df['IMG_TIR2'].values)
        simulated_bt_tir2_all.extend(df['sim_bt_tir2'].values)

# Convert lists to numpy arrays
observed_bt_tir1_all = np.array(observed_bt_tir1_all)
simulated_bt_tir1_all = np.array(simulated_bt_tir1_all)
observed_bt_tir2_all = np.array(observed_bt_tir2_all)
simulated_bt_tir2_all = np.array(simulated_bt_tir2_all)

# Calculate CDFs for observed and simulated BTs
sorted_obs_tir1, obs_cdf_tir1 = calculate_cdf(observed_bt_tir1_all)
sorted_sim_tir1, sim_cdf_tir1 = calculate_cdf(simulated_bt_tir1_all)
sorted_obs_tir2, obs_cdf_tir2 = calculate_cdf(observed_bt_tir2_all)
sorted_sim_tir2, sim_cdf_tir2 = calculate_cdf(simulated_bt_tir2_all)

# Map observed CDF to simulated BTs
corrected_bt_tir1 = map_observed_cdf_to_simulated(observed_bt_tir1_all, obs_cdf_tir1, sim_cdf_tir1, sorted_sim_tir1)
corrected_bt_tir2 = map_observed_cdf_to_simulated(observed_bt_tir2_all, obs_cdf_tir2, sim_cdf_tir2, sorted_sim_tir2)

But when I plotted the scatterplot before and after correction I got this:

And I also want to plot a bivariate density plot. But this gives me an unexpected result:
# Calculate statistics before and after correction
bias_before_tir1, std_before_tir1, corr_before_tir1, num_points_before_tir1 = calculate_statistics(observed_bt_tir1_all, simulated_bt_tir1_all)
bias_after_tir1, std_after_tir1, corr_after_tir1, num_points_after_tir1 = calculate_statistics(corrected_bt_tir1, simulated_bt_tir1_all)

# Bivariate density plots of observed vs. simulated BTs before and after correction
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 6))

# Before Correction
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
sns.kdeplot(x=simulated_bt_tir1_all, y=observed_bt_tir1_all, fill=True, cmap='Blues', thresh=0, levels=100)
plt.plot([min(simulated_bt_tir1_all), max(simulated_bt_tir1_all)], [min(simulated_bt_tir1_all), max(simulated_bt_tir1_all)], 'k--', label='Ideal')
plt.xlabel('Simulated BT (K)')
plt.ylabel('Observed BT (K)')
plt.title('Observed vs Simulated BTs Before Correction')

# Annotate with statistics
plt.text(0.05, 0.95, f'Bias = {bias_before_tir1:.2f} K\nStd = {std_before_tir1:.2f} K\nCorr. Coef. = {corr_before_tir1:.2f}\nNo. of points = {num_points_before_tir1}', 
         transform=plt.gca().transAxes, fontsize=10, verticalalignment='top', bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=0.5))

# After Correction
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
sns.kdeplot(x=simulated_bt_tir1_all, y=corrected_bt_tir1, fill=True, cmap='Reds', thresh=0, levels=100)
plt.plot([min(simulated_bt_tir1_all), max(simulated_bt_tir1_all)], [min(simulated_bt_tir1_all), max(simulated_bt_tir1_all)], 'k--', label='Ideal')
plt.xlabel('Simulated BT (K)')
plt.ylabel('Corrected Observed BT (K)')
plt.title('Corrected Observed vs Simulated BTs After Correction')

# Annotate with statistics
plt.text(0.05, 0.95, f'Bias = {bias_after_tir1:.2f} K\nStd = {std_after_tir1:.2f} K\nCorr. Coef. = {corr_after_tir1:.2f}\nNo. of points = {num_points_after_tir1}', 
         transform=plt.gca().transAxes, fontsize=10, verticalalignment='top', bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=0.5))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()



Your code is quite long, and difficult to follow, especially as it is missing reproducible test data.  At first sight, the calculations are done in 1D, while the plots are for 2D data, which doesn't seem to make sense. Anyway, it is recommended to test and plot each of the steps separately, to find out where the code differs from what's expected.
